# configuring Cache Class vs. Caching with HTTP headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

I have asp.net mvc web application, using .net 3.5

I want to use caching in the UI Logic layer.

I read about

1- `Cache Class`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.90).aspx

2- `Caching with HTTP headers`

http://www.dotnetperls.com/cache

I'm not sure what's the difference and which one I should use.

Furthermore how do I configure the caching in each of them?

item 1- Only in web config?

item 2- Only programmaticly ?

**update:**

I have tried

using System.Web.Caching;

```
    private string GetTitlePerBDataId(Guid changeRequestDataId)
    {
        var key = string.Format("{0}_{1}", TITLE, changeRequestDataId);

        if (System.Web.Caching.Cache[key] == null)
        {
            Cache[key] = mBundlatorServiceHelper.GetData(changeRequestBundleDataId).Title;
        }

        return Convert.ToString(Cache[key]);           
    }
```

`But got class name is not valid in this point` over `Cache`

Comment: If you are talking about some internal business layer, how does http cache apply?

Comment: So how I configure item (1) ?

Comment: what have you tried? have you read the documentation? Also note that in 4.0 there is a non-web cache too, but if your code is MVC, the regular web cache is just fine.

Comment: what is ` the regular web cache` which is just fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cache class is in memory caching, on the server. 
You can Cache objects and other stuff there.

Caching with http headers, defines how the client/proxy caches the output.

if you look at the documentation for System.Web.Caching.Cache it says

> Information about an instance of this class is available through the
>   Cache property of the HttpContext object or the Cache property of the
>   Page object.

So you can only use it though httpcontext.

```
private string GetTitlePerBDataId(Guid changeRequestDataId)
{
    var key = string.Format("{0}_{1}", TITLE, changeRequestDataId);

    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] == null)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, mBundlatorServiceHelper.GetData(changeRequestBundleDataId).Title);
    }


    return Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[key]);           
}
```